# I am looking with tasklist how do i find the pid?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

in chrome how i find PID of a website so a taskkill by PID of the site not taskkill all of chrome?  TASKKILL /IM chrome.exe /F i on windows 7 thanks
i got tab open stack,google, youtube

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/j4bff.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The PID is assigned by the Operating System, and isn't based on the content of the page or anything like that. You can kill a certain PID using the `/fi` option, so I think the following works:

```
taskkill /f /im /fi PID [pid value]
```

As for working out which tab is associated with which PID, I'm not sure but I'd guess the only way would be through using another tool to examine the process and maybe,**maybe**, find some information which would allow you to find it. Apart from that guesswork is all I can think of. For example if you opened youtube last, it would be logical to assume (but not necessarily 100% accurate) that it would have the highest PID. If I remember correctly not every chrome process is for a tab either. I think there are extra ones for background components too.

Edit: Just to point out this is if you're trying to script it. Chrome task manager would allow you to do this if you're doing it manually `shift+esc`

Comment: it's just `taskkill /pid 3752` (you can also give `/f` for "force", but `/IM` and `FI` don't belong there). See `taskkill /?` for proper syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the tab bar of Chrome, and click "Task Manager" (or type Shift-Esc). You will see a list of all loaded extensions and tabs. There should be a column named "Process ID" containing what you are looking for.

Also, note that this will not actually close the tab, just force its process to die, and render a "Aw, snap!" page instead.

If you're looking to get the PID of the tab using batch directly, then you will probably need an external tool to inspect the list of processes, and find which one is associated with the correct tab.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you will be successful in finding a specific PID per Google page. Here is what the command line of most Google processes looks like as seen in SysInternals Process Explorer. It would be great if someone could point to some documentation on these parameters.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
 --type=renderer
 --enable-features=AutomaticTabDiscarding<AutomaticTabDiscarding,UsePasswordSeparatedSigninFlow<PasswordSeparatedSigninFlow
 --disable-features=
 DocumentWriteEvaluator<DisallowFetchForDocWrittenScriptsInMainFrame
 ,UpdateRendererPriorityOnStartup<UpdateRendererPriorityOnStartup
 --force-fieldtrials=
 AppBannerTriggering/Aggressive
/AutofillProfileOrderByFrecency/Enabled
/*AutomaticTabDiscarding/Enabled_Once_10-gen2
/CaptivePortalInterstitial/Enabled
/*ChildAccountDetection/Disabled
/*ClientSideDetectionModel/Model0
/DirectWriteFontProxy/UseDirectWriteFontProxy
/*DisallowFetchForDocWrittenScriptsInMainFrame/Default
/*EnableMediaRouter/Disabled/ExtensionDeveloperModeWarning/Enabled
/*GFE/Default
/GoogleBrandedContextMenu/default
/InstanceID/Enabled
/MaterialDesignDownloads/Enabled
/*NetworkQualityEstimator/Enabled
/OfferUploadCreditCards/Enabled
/*OmniboxBundledExperimentV1/Unused_2
/OutOfProcessPac/Default
/*PasswordBranding/Disabled
/*PasswordGeneration/Disabled
/*PasswordManagerSettingsMigration/Disable
/PasswordSeparatedSigninFlow/Enabled
/PasswordSmartBubble/Default
/*QUIC/TcpBBRJuly
/ReportCertificateErrors/ShowAndPossiblySend
/*ResourcePriorities/Control25PermanentA
/SHA1IdentityUIWarning/Enabled
/SHA1ToolbarUIJanuary2016/Warning
/SHA1ToolbarUIJanuary2017/Error
/*SRTPromptFieldTrial/On
/SSLCommonNameMismatchHandling/Enabled
/*SafeBrowsingIncidentReportingService/Default
/SafeBrowsingUnverifiedDownloads/DisableByParameterMostSbTypes2
/SafeBrowsingUpdateFrequency/Default
/*SchedulerExpensiveTaskBlocking/Enabled
/SyncHttpContentCompression/Enabled
/*TriggeredResetFieldTrial/On
/*UMA-Dynamic-Uniformity-Trial/Group6
/*UMA-Population-Restrict/normal
/*UMA-Uniformity-Trial-1-Percent/group_11
/*UMA-Uniformity-Trial-10-Percent/group_06
/*UMA-Uniformity-Trial-100-Percent/group_01
/*UMA-Uniformity-Trial-20-Percent/group_01
/*UMA-Uniformity-Trial-5-Percent/group_02
/*UMA-Uniformity-Trial-50-Percent/group_01
/*UMA_CheckStates/Checks/
 --primordial-pipe-token=BCDFCAA2140262C34D823F0FBA318631
 --lang=en-US
 --extension-process
 --enable-webrtc-hw-h264-encoding
 --enable-offline-auto-reload
 --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only
 --enable-pinch
 --device-scale-factor=1
 --num-raster-threads=4
 --content-image-texture-target=3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553
 --video-image-texture-target=3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553,3553
 --mojo-channel-token=1B5775475A7DAF40FF13EF69EFC7290F
 --mojo-application-channel-token=883D599311A646E979D0BF6EEC940AD2
 --channel="9228.16.626922434\147311849"
 --mojo-platform-channel-handle=4512 /prefetch:1
```